# std::chrono - fixed time step loop

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, game-loop

I'm trying to make fixed time step loop with using < chrono >.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start;
    const double timePerFrame = 1.0 / 60.0;
    double accumulator = 0.0;
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        while(accumulator >= timePerFrame)
        {
            accumulator -= timePerFrame;
            std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
            //update();
        }
        accumulator += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
        //render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Value of variable "i" is printed less then 60 times a second. The same situation takes place when I'm trying to change "timePerFrame" to "1.0". What is wrong with it?

Comment: `1.0 / 60.0` is not a exactly representable number

Comment: Console windows aren't really designed for high performance scrolling....

Comment: I have code of fixed time step loop what is made by using other clock and it works with no problems, but this one with chrono clocks prints about 17 messages per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using Framerate = duration<steady_clock::rep, std::ratio<1, 60>>;
    auto next = steady_clock::now() + Framerate{1};
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
        //update();
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next);
        next += Framerate{1};
        //render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the same thing with a busy loop:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using Framerate = duration<steady_clock::rep, std::ratio<1, 60>>;
    auto next = steady_clock::now() + Framerate{1};
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
        //update();
        while (steady_clock::now() < next)
            ;
        next += Framerate{1};
        //render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have read that "sleep" functions shouldn't be used in fixed time step loops.

Comment: @AkasataAkasata:  It is true that a sleep can wake up arbitrarily late.  If you prefer a busy loop, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: It would be great, because I really don't know what's wrong with loop what I made.

Comment: @HowardHinnant is busy loop same as the use of NOP in for loops as in Assembly or C programming?